# Too many connection errors MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database, network-programming, database-connection

I have a C# application which runs on LAN computers as client and accesses MySQL database present on the server. In my testing environment the application is running without any problems.

However, in one of the client's place for some reason there are intermittent MySQL connections being terminated or being Timed out. I am faced with such errors:

> *Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time or the connection host has failed to respond.*

**Timeout IO**

NOTE: I have not changed the default connection Timeout. And the data fetched are just a few records, nothing big.

One of the computers encountered so many errors that it was blocked by MySQL had to flush hosts and increase connection error limit so that it doesn't happen again.

To me it seems to be a LAN networking issue however, I am newbie so it would great if you could give me advice as to how should I proceed further? Are there any tools through which I can monitor why this connection errors are happening?

Note: Moreover, the server error logs have nothing in them. There were 339 aborted connections when only 6 PCs have this app running that too only for 2 days.

Moreover, stackstrace shows that these are socket exceptions.

**EDIT**: I am adding the stack trace for more information.

```
System.TimeoutException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

Comment: " I unchecked the host-name-resolve and it seems that the problem is solved. However still early to conclude." => delete for now and restore later or create a new question if needed

Comment: How are you creating/destroying connections? Are you using `using` statements? Are you closing/disposing connections when you are done with them? Are you catching errors where needed and closing connections (a feature of a `using` statement)?

Comment: @RonBeyer Ya that is not the case I am not using 'using statement' right now but I specifically checked that all connections are being closed once opened. Moreover there is no increase in the number of connection threads as per Client connection tab in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Guys suggestions please...